# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CAN_RAW'

Tags: python-2.7, can-bus

I am writing a simple python script to read data from a CAN bus. I used the python_can library for python 2.7. It contains a class called CANopenNode and inside the __init_ method I write:

```
self.bus = can.interface.Bus(channel = 'can0', bustype = 'socketcan_native')
```

when I run the code it reports the error like this:

```
File "/home/jxu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/can/interface.py", line 87, in __new__
return cls(channel, **kwargs)
File "/home/jxu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/can/interfaces/socketcan/socketcan_native.py", line 416, in __init__
self.socket = create_socket(CAN_RAW)
File "/home/jxu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/can/interfaces/socketcan/socketcan_native.py", line 305, in create_socket
if can_protocol is None or can_protocol == socket.CAN_RAW:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CAN_RAW'
```

The relative lines of code in create_socket (inside library) looks like this:

```
if can_protocol is None or can_protocol == socket.CAN_RAW:
    can_protocol = socket.CAN_RAW
    socket_type = socket.SOCK_RAW
elif can_protocol == socket.CAN_BCM:
    can_protocol = socket.CAN_BCM
    socket_type = socket.SOCK_DGRAM
sock = socket.socket(socket.PF_CAN, socket_type, can_protocol)
```

The library files seem no wrong:

```
>>> import socket
>>> print socket.__file__
/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.pyc
```

Can anyone explain what the CAN_RAW means here and why this error is, thanks!

Comment: The top of that file states *This implementation is for versions of Python that have native can socket and can bcm socket support.*. It looks like the library selected the wrong module from multiple choices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You picked the `socketcan_native` bus:

```
bustype = 'socketcan_native'
```

However, according to the [*SocketCAN* interface documentation](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/interfaces/socketcan.html), you can't use that option on Python 2.7:

> There are two implementations of socketcan backends. One written with ctypes to be compatible with Python 2 and 3, and one written for future versions of Python3 which feature native support.
>
> [...]
>
> Unless you’re running Python3.3 or lower the recommended backend is `socketcan_native`. **For Python2.7 and Python3 <3.4, the available backend is `socketcan_ctypes`.**

Switch to using `socketcan_ctypes`:

```
self.bus = can.interface.Bus(channel = 'can0', bustype = 'socketcan_ctypes')
```

or, and this is *much better*, use the `socketcan` interface; this triggers auto-detection of the right interface to use for your current system.

The specific [`socket.CAN_RAW` constant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.AF_CAN) was added in Python 3.3, which is why trying to use `socketcan_native` fails to find the name in Python 2.7. The `socketcan_native` implementation also needs [`socket.CAN_BCM`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.CAN_BCM) to be available, which was added in Python 3.4.

Comment: You are correct! Also I found the bustype should be just 'socketcan', or 
it will meet NotImplementedError in site-packages/can/util.py. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @JeremyXu: interesting; `socketcan` does auto-detection anyway and is much preferable.

Comment: @JeremyXu: and the `NotImplementError` would be raised for an interface type that doesn't exist; either you made a typo in the bustype name, or you have a version of `python-can` that doesn't have the name `socketcan_ctypes`.